# How to detect new line in this scenario

Tags: c

I'm solving some projects exercises. I came across this sentence and I need some clarification. The program asks the user to enter parentheses and/or braces and checks if they are nested or not. First, I need to read the user's input as follows:

```
while( (ch = getchar()) != '\n' ){
     // Do analysis on ch. 
}
```

But I came across the following sentence which is not clear to me.

> When the program reads the new-line character, have it check whether
>   the stack is empty

According to my aforementioned while(), I will never catch new line character. How can I overcome this issue? The only thing I'm thinking of is to check the stack size after while completes, if so, it means the user enters a new line character causing while() loop to terminates. But this solution doesn't catch the new line, it is rather a workaround. Any suggestion!

Comment: When the program reads the new-line character, your while-loop will exit, so you know.

Comment: You also need to check for EOF.

Comment: I think it's quite ambiguous. Do you have to continue in analysis after a `\n`? If it's you have to check for `EOF` in while guard and check the `\n` inside the while-body else you just have to add `EOF` check in the guard and then exit the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
while( (ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF){
     // Do analysis on ch. 
}
if (ch=='\n') {
    //check your paranthesis stack
}
```

Probably you should check your stack both upon `\n` and EOF.

Answer (score -1):

> The only thing I'm thinking of is to check the stack size after while completes, if so, it means the user enters a new line character causing while() loop to terminates.

This is exactly right.

Your code should look like

```
while ( (ch = getchar()) != '\n' ) {
     // Do analysis on ch. 
}
// check whether stack is empty
```

Because at the end of the loop you know `ch` contains a newline.